# Android - Keeping users logged in not working (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my application I am trying to keep the user logged in, after they log in the first time. This is not working.

In my application I have multiple usertypes: "School" and "Students". In my activity I have the AuthStateListener method, but nothing happens in my activity. The application just sticks to the starting activity without running the code in the AuthStateListener method.

```
 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
           FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
           if (user != null) {
               // User is signed in
               rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       if (dataSnapshot.child("usertype").getValue(String.class).equals("Students") && dataSnapshot.child("verified").getValue(boolean.class).equals(true)) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(WaitingActivity.this, StudentsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }


                        if (dataSnapshot.child("usertype").getValue(String.class).equals("School") && dataSnapshot.child("verified").getValue(boolean.class).equals(true)) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(WaitingActivity.this, SchoolsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Intent intent = new Intent(WaitingActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or have I missed something?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the first line in the callback (`FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();`) does it get triggered? Also make sure you don't ignore errors and `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check login state every time that an Activity starts or resumes, you have two options.

You can use code like this in the Activity's `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in, do whatever you need to do
} else {
    // User is not signed in, do whatever you need to do
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `AuthStateListener` as you indicated, but make sure that you add the listener:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
```

Just make sure that you remove the `AuthStateListener` at an appropriate time using the `removeAuthStateListener()` method.

Comment: Listener also runs [immediately after the listener is added](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener).

Comment: @Bob Snyder, thank you for the clarification!  I have corrected my answer to include that information.